# pg 0.14.1: dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _PQconnectdb

Tags: macos, rubygems, osx-elcapitan, pg

Running postgresql 9.4.5 and pg 0.14.1 on El Capitan, and experiencing the following error followed by an exit from the Rails console when performing the first query:

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _PQconnectdb
>     Referenced from: /Users/christian/Documents/Development/onelogin.com/vendor/bundle/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle
>     Expected in: flat namespace
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: _PQconnectdb
>     Referenced from: /Users/christian/Documents/Development/onelogin.com/vendor/bundle/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle
>     Expected in: flat namespace
>
> Trace/BPT trap: 5

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This means that the `libpq` library the gem was compiled against is missing or is no longer loadable for some reason. Oftentimes you'll need to reinstall PostgreSQL after an OS upgrade, or after installing a new version of the XCode command line tools.

You can look at the library the gem is trying to load like this (on OSX anyway):

`file $(otool -L /Users/christian/Documents/Development/onelogin.com/vendor/bundle/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle | grep libpq | cut -f1 -d' ')`

It should look something like this:

`/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64`

My PostgreSQL is installed via Homebrew, so your path might be different, but it should at least show a shared library. If it looks okay, post what it says in a comment and I'll try to help further.