# Cannot find _PQconnectiondb Diesel Rust

Tags: rust, apple-m1, rust-diesel

I'm using a Mac M1. I have managed to install the diesel client, and the postgres driver (I can connect to postgres with sqlalchemy on the same laptop). However, whenever I try and run the rust diesel client I get the following error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _PQconnectdb
  Referenced from: /Users/maxwellflitton/.cargo/bin/diesel
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _PQconnectdb
  Referenced from: /Users/maxwellflitton/.cargo/bin/diesel
  Expected in: flat namespace

zsh: abort
```

I have the following config in a config file at `/Users/maxwellflitton/.cargo/config` with the following contents:

```
[target.x86_64-apple-darwin]
rustflags = [
  "-C", "link-arg=-undefined",
  "-C", "link-arg=dynamic_lookup",
]

[target.aarch64-apple-darwin]
rustflags = [
  "-C", "link-arg=-undefined",
  "-C", "link-arg=dynamic_lookup",
]
```

and I have the following configuration:

- **Rust:** rustc 1.51.0 (2fd73fabe 2021-03-23)
- **Diesel:** `{ version = "1.4.4", features = ["postgres"] }`
- **Database:** postgres
- **Operating System:** MacOs Big Sur 11.2.3 M1 chip

Comment: You need to provide a library that contains this (and other symbols). Just telling the linker to ignore undefined symbols does not solve your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pg 0.14.1: dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: \_PQconnectdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34196607/pg-0-14-1-dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-not-found-pqconnectdb)

Comment: I'm now getting this: ```libpq is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because conflicts with postgres formula.```

Comment: How to I provide the library???